# find method not finding what it should in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting the strangest behavour from the ActiveRecord find method.  I am trying to find a record by the updated_at date, but it's returning [].
Here's the code:

```
      @updated = get_current_user.ideas.all(:conditions => {:updated_at => '2013-04-20 03:30:34'})
```

And here is the record that is supposed to be returned:

```
 #<Idea id: 3, title: "An app that tracks useage", status: "prototype", user_id: 1, updated_at: "2013-04-20 03:30:34"
```

I got it working for like 2 seconds,  then, nothing.  The problem seems to be that it won't match the updated_at attribute.  It just returns empty array.
Does anyone know why it's not working?

Comment: `I got it working for like 2 seconds` Did you happen to update the record during those two seconds?

Comment: I don't think so.  I went into the console and double-checked the value

Answer (score 1):

Is your user has an associations with ideas? from your record, I dont see the user id. I did same query and I can retrieve my answer. Also, you can check if your get_current_user is correct.

Comment: Yes.  And there is a user_id,  but the terminal wouldn't let me copy/paste and I was too lazy to write it all out.  And,  get_current_user returns correctly.  Thanks

Comment: then it's weird :S Can you try this? @updated = get_current_user.ideas.where(updated_at: '2013-04-20 03:30:34') and get_current_user.ideas which will return an array edy.

Comment: I tried the former.  and I checked that get_current_user.ideas does in fact return an array.  In fact, I copied the updated_at value from the item I want returned in that array that got returned and pasted it into my where statement.  I even tried a search directly on the database and got no return

Comment: search directly in the database also got no return? no record exists? try restart your server console or whatever >.<

Comment: No such luck.  Still getting nil

Comment: do you mind to post your rails console log when you try to trigger the query? (the query, and query idea record as well ), update your ques to let others know more.

Comment: I figured it out!  Can't compare string and datetime and expect a match!  Silly me

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@updated = get_current_user.ideas.where(:updated_at => '2013-04-20 03:30:34').all
```

it seems that all(:conditions => '') is hard to remember and will be deprecated in newer rails versions. I am not sure. whatever, I prefer the 'where' method than 'all'.

Comment: Thanks,  I tried that code and still got nothing to return :(

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I forgot that the datetime was in fact a datetime and tried to compare it to a string.  That does not work.  Thanks all for helping out